# Swissonic Sub10 standby mode issue

Tags: hardware, monitors, subwoofer

I bought Swissonic Sub10 and it makes "pop" in my monitors every time it goes into standby mode. It's so annoying and maybe even harmful to my speakers.
Does anyone know how to get rid of this option? What should I unpin or desolder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid running your front L/R through the sub. Send to them separately.

It's a design fault in the unit. If it's new you could send it back.

From the reviews at [Thomann](https://www.thomann.de/gb/swissonic_sub10_reviews.htm?sid=b7e8c7257daa05cde8f33e35f8b416c4)

> My only gripe is that the power saving feature is nifty, but using the satellite outs from the sub causes the satellites to pop every time you wake the sub from sleep mode, which isn't great. avoided the problem by using a Presonus Monitor Station 2 which allowed me to hook up the sub and my main speakers to separate outs.

Comment: how to avoid running L/R via sub ? That's how sub crossover works.

Comment: The crossover isn't actually a crossover, it's a high-pass filter, so it does nothing to the pass-through.

Comment: ok so if I connect them separately to my Fireface UCX and turn up all the way subwoofer crossover knob to 180 Hz and then put LPF on it in my TotalMix at 80Hz and also put HPF at 80Hz for my monitors it should do the work? (စ‿စ )

Comment: I don't know, as I've not used any of that equipment. Try it & see.

Comment: I'm sure it will work but I don't know if it won't cause any hidden issues.

Comment: Whichever way you do it you're going to have to re-measure the room to see whan it's flat - so a bit of trial & error won't go amiss.